# Signing and packaging the Xamarin application using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to publish a Xamarin.Forms project with Visual Studio 2015
by following the steps [on this address](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#Create_a_New_Keystore).

What I have done so far :
I have changed the to project's build configuration as Release mode
and have created the keystore then published
and run the project in release mode,
so the apk files have been created in Release folder.

But in my Visual Studio, there isn't an option as `Package [project] for Android (.apk)`
[image]

Here is my debug menu:
[image]

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you have pre 4.2.6 Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been renamed to `Export Android Package (.apk)`

Answer (score 1):

Select the project root and go to Tools->Android->Publish Android App

[image]

As your link says, this is the new and easier way to do this.